# Is there a way to switch between angular material tabs based on a form submission from contents of those tabs?

Tags: angular, mat-tab

I am working on an angular web app. I require to control my angular tabs based on actiions performed in the contents of those tabs. For instance I have the following tabs:
Item Information,
Variations,
Pricing ,
Inventory, etc
and these tabs contain forms loaded by angular components. I want to automatically switch to Variations tab when Item Information form submits successfully. Also, user should not be able to switch to variations tab before saving item information.

```
<mat-tab-group class=" navbar-default panel-piluku  nav nav-justified nav-wizard nav-progression" > 
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Item Info" label="Item Info">
    <add-product-information></add-product-information>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Variations" label="Variations">
    <add-product-variation></add-product-variation>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Pricing" label="Pricing">
      <add-product-pricing></add-product-pricing>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Inventory" label="Inventory">
      <add-product-stock></add-product-stock>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Images" label="Images">
    <add-product-images></add-product-images>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Locations" label="Locations">
    <add-product-locations></add-product-locations>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

````````
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private productsService: ProductsService, private router: Router, public dialog: MatDialog, private suppliersService: SuppliersService) { }
  submitProduct = function(){
    this.product["sku"] = this.sku;
    this.product["alternate_sku"] = this.alternate_sku;
    this.product["product_name"] = this.product_name;
    this.product["product_description"] = this.product_description;
    this.product["category"] = this.category_id;
    this.product["price_per_unit"] = this.price_per_unit;
    this.product["reorder_level"] = this.reorder_level;
    this.product["discontinued"] = this.discontinued;
    this.product["cost"] = this.cost;
    this.product["default_price"] = this.default_price;
    this.product["best_price"] = this.best_price;
    this.product["medium_price"] = this.medium_price;
    this.product["brand"] = this.brand;
    this.product["upc"] = this.upc;
    this.productsService.addProduct(this.product).subscribe((data)=>{
      ````Here the tab should switch```````
    });
````````

```
<form action="submitProduct()" id="item_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

  <input type="hidden" name="ecommerce_product_id" value="" />
...
...
...

      <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" name="submitf" value="Save" id="submitf"
          (click)="submitProduct()" class="submit_button floating-button btn btn-lg btn-primary" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: there is ``[selectedIndex]`` input for ``mat-tab-group`` . So you can change it to change the tabs

Comment: Yes but how can I do that from another component? notice that my components have changed :\

Comment: Its very simple, use an event emitter to notify changes to your tab component

Comment: I am new to angular. Haven't done that ever.

Comment: Can you share how exactly is your form and tab component related ?

Comment: Can you put your code in stackblitz, So that me or contributors can go through it and can help you more easily & conveniently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can control the tab selected using the `selectIndex` input to the `mat-tab-group` . 
To Change the tabSelected , set it to the tab index you need and the tab changes to the set index.

To do that i would simply define a service and use behavior subjects .
My service definition :

`my-tab.service.ts` :

```
@Injectable()

export class MyTabService{
 tabSubject : BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

 constructor(){}

 setTabSelected(tabIndex : number){
  this.tabSubject.next(tabIndex);
 } 

 getTabSelected() {
  this.tabSubject.asObservable();
 }
}
```

Now Subscribe to `getTabSelected()` in your tabs component and you'll get the `tabIndex` in the subscription response .

Considering your tabs component to be `my-tab.component.ts` ,

```
@Component({...})
export class MyTabComponent {
 selectdIndex : number = 0;
 constructor(private _myTabService : MyTabService){}

 ngOnInit(){

 this.-myTabService.getTabSelected().subscribe((tabIndex : number) =>{
  this.selectedIndex = tabIndex;
 })

...
 }
...
}
```

Use the selectedIndex in your template :

```
<mat-tab-group class=" navbar-default panel-piluku  nav nav-justified nav-wizard nav-progression" [selectedIndex]='selectedIndex'> 
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Item Info" label="Item Info">
    <add-product-information></add-product-information>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Variations" label="Variations">
    <add-product-variation></add-product-variation>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Pricing" label="Pricing">
      <add-product-pricing></add-product-pricing>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Inventory" label="Inventory">
      <add-product-stock></add-product-stock>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Images" label="Images">
    <add-product-images></add-product-images>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="outbound_link" role="button" title="Locations" label="Locations">
    <add-product-locations></add-product-locations>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

For more information on inputs and events in mat tab group refer : [Mat Tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup)

Comment: how about the tab restriction?

Comment: @LailaSamaviaKhan just disable the tabs to restrict user from going to other tabs using ``disabled`` input

Comment: @LailaSamaviaKhan if my answer helped you please mark it as answer :)